# ERROR Unexpected function expression when "firebase deploy"

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, expo

I am using React-Native and Expo.
I am doing Push Notification for my application.
When the user receives a new task, it will show a notification by expo.

This is the code for Firebase index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var fetch = require('node-fetch')



const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

//send the push notification 
exports.sendPushNotification = 
functions.database.ref('Task/').onCreate(event => {

const root = event.data.ref.root
var messages = []

//return the main promise 
return root.child('/users').once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {

        var expoToken = childSnapshot.val().expoToken;

        messages.push({
            "to": expoToken,
            "sound": "default",
            "body": "New Task Added"
        });
    });
    //firebase.database then() respved a single promise that resolves
    //once all the messages have been resolved 
    return Promise.all(messages)

})
    .then(messages => {
        // console.log(messages)
        fetch('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(messages)

        });
    })
    .catch(reason => {
        console.log(reason)
    })


});
```

**I got the following error when I do "firebase deploy"**

[image]

Can someone please kindly assist me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

---

**from this**

---

```
 facts = queryRecords().then(function(result) {
    return result.data 
}).catch(function(error) {
    facts = error 
});
```

---

**to this**

---

```
 facts = queryRecords().then(result => {
    return result.data 
}).catch(error => {
    facts = error 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking a the error messages, it seems the error comes from the fact you don't return anything in the following `then`:

```
.then(messages => {
        // console.log(messages)
        fetch(...);
})
```

I've never used node-fetch, but based on the documentation it seems you just have to return the promise returned by `fetch()`, as follows:

```
.then(messages => {
        // console.log(messages)
        return fetch(...);
})
```

Note that this is not only important from an eslint perspective but also for a correct execution of your Cloud Function. I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

---

Finally, note that eslint also gives you a warning on [using arrow functions for callbacks](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-arrow-callback).

You might adapt the following piece of code

```
return root.child('/users').once('value').then(function (snapshot) {})
```

to

```
return root.child('/users').once('value').then(snapshot => {})
```

The same for `snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {})`.

Answer (score 0):

from this:

```
request({
    url: "https://test.com",
    method: "POST",
    auth: {
      username: username,
      password: password,
    },
    json: {a : 'a'}, function(error, response, body) {
    // Print the error if one occurred
    console.log("error:", error);
    // Print the response status code if a response was received
    console.log("statusCode:", response && response.statusCode);
    // Prints the response of the request.
    console.log("body:", body);
  });
```

to this , solved

```
request({
url: "https://test.com",
method: "POST",
auth: {
  username: username,
  password: password,
},
json: {a : 'a'}, (error, response, body) => {
// Print the error if one occurred
console.log("error:", error);
// Print the response status code if a response was received
console.log("statusCode:", response && response.statusCode);
// Prints the response of the request.
console.log("body:", body);
```

});

changes : (error, response, body) =>